# Single Responsibility Principle in Jenkins Blue-Green Deployment

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build a kind of [Blue-Green Deployment](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) using Jenkins' Pipeline. It should call separate jobs to fulfill the whole process. Assuming I got two servers available for a loadbalancer: **web1** and **web2**. My idea is to implement following steps:

1. checkout from SVN
2. build project
3. run Unit-Tests
4. deploy project to **web2**
5. run Selenium-Tests on **web2**
6. add **web2** to the loadbalancer
7. remove **web1** from the loadbalancer
8. deploy project to **web1**
9. remove **web2** from the loadbalancer
10. add **web1** to the loadbalancer

This workflow allows to use the secondary server as pure testing machine, while ensuring the availability of the project.

However, while the deployment should run only once per day due to technical reasons, I want at least the unit test job run for every commit, so that my colleagues will immediately get feedback and reports (*Continuous Integration*).

The *Deploy-Jobs* should also be build manually with specific development-servers as parameter.

Needless to say, the jobs are dependent on each other, e.g.:

- *Build* depends on *Checkout*
- *Unit-Tests* depend on *Build*

Step 4 and step 8 should be the same jobs, as well as step 6 and 10, and 7 and 9, all controlled via parameters.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Thanks in advance for your help!